# Can a cylinder be regarded as a Riemannian manifold?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, curvature

Consider the surface of a bounded cylinder consisting of a top,bottom and side part together with the metric induced by the euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Can this space be regarded as a Riemannian manifold? If so, what would be the smoothness? It's obvious that the given embedding is nonsmooth but I wonder if we can choose charts such that the transition maps are smooth. Except for the edges the space is locally isometric to the plane so the curvature is zero except for the edges. What would be the curvature, if defined, on the edges?
This problem arose because I was trying to find a simple example of a nonsmooth Riemannian manifold where it is easy to compute geodesics. The cylinder seemed to be a good candidate to me.

Comment: You could consider it as a CAT(n) space, perhaps...

Comment: The boundary of any convex body in $\mathbb R^n$ has a natural metric (the infimum of lengths of curves joining the given points), and it has nonnegative curvature in the comparison sense. The curvature at nonsmooth points is infinite. See any book on metric geometry, e.g. Burago-Burago-Ivanov.